# Creating diff and merge tool using TkTreeCtrl and TCL

Tags: user-interface, tree, tcl, tk-toolkit

i usually work on TCL scripting a lot but has never worked on TK before and now i am working on a project where i need to develop a diff/merge tool.

So i thought of using TkTreeCtrl because tool will be used to diff between two tree structures. Now i was looking at the tutorial of TKTreeCtrl and playing with it developing a gui and checking other options.

Now i am not sure if i am thinking correctly but i initially thought of having two columns with separate tree structure which are to be diffed and merged based on the back end logic we will have. But after started playing with some basic tktreectrl commands of creating columns, elements, items etc, it seems like we can have only one column that could have a tree structure. But since i need to create two tk tree structures side by side, i am not sure how to do it.

After going through the tktreectrl demo [here](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/Understanding%20TkTreeCtrl.html) i was able to create different columns and populating them with elements and items, but i don't know how to create two different tree structures side by side for comparison.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious answer would seem to be to create two (or more) TkTreeCtrl, one for each tree structure. Your code can work with the contents of both controls at once and also synchronize them as needed.

Comment: Well but as far as i understand, we can only have one tree hierarchical structure in any column of tktree at any time. I am not sure how to create two tktreectrl together?

Comment: @PuneetMittal: `pack [treectrl .t1] [treectrl .t2] -side left` gives me two `treectrl` controls side by side. Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am very new to Tk so took some time to figure out how all widgets and geometry manager works. I got what i wanted. Thanks.